# Azure Pipeline step reference task manual validation at version 0.198 which is not valid for the given job target

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml

I am writing a simple `azure-pipelines.yml` to install terraform and do a **manual approval** before proceeding to the terraform apply. I get the below error:

> Job manual_approval: Step reference task manual validation at version '0.198.0' which is not valid for the given job target

Here's my yaml.

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- test

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:

  - job: install_terraform
    displayName: "Installing Terraform"
    steps:
      - task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-installer-task.TerraformInstaller@0
        displayName: 'Install Terraform latest'

  - job: terraform_init
    displayName: "Terraform Init"
    dependsOn: install_terraform
    steps:
      - task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-release-task.TerraformTaskV2@2
        displayName: 'Terraform : init'
        inputs:
          workingDirectory: Terraform
          backendServiceArm: 'managedclouds-rnd-001 (xxxx)'
          backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: 'ssi-tf-state'
          backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: tfstatessi
          backendAzureRmContainerName: tfstate
          backendAzureRmKey: tfstate

  - job: manual_approval
    displayName: "Manual Approval"
    dependsOn: terraform_init
    steps:
      - task: ManualValidation@0
        timeoutInMinutes: 5
        inputs:
          instructions: "Hi, please validate"

  - job: terrform_apply
    displayName: "Terraform Apply"
    dependsOn: manual_approval   
    steps:    
      - task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-release-task.TerraformTaskV2@2
        displayName: 'Terraform : Apply'
        inputs:
          command: apply
          workingDirectory: Terraform
          environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'managedclouds-rnd-001 (xxxx)'
```

Can someone please help me, I am new to azure devops.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Azure Pipeline step reference task manual validation at version 0.198 which is not valid for the given job target

You should specify the `pool: server` for that task:

```
- job: manual_approval
  displayName: "Manual Approval"
  dependsOn: terraform_init
  pool: server
  steps:
  - task: ManualValidation@0
    timeoutInMinutes: 5
    inputs:
      instructions: "Hi, please validate"
```

[image]

Please check the [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-validation?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for some more details.

Comment: "pool: server" is actually required and not optional for this task, so the 1st Answer is correct.

Comment: Honestly I don't understand this answer. In my case, I already have the pool defined at the job level like that :

    pool:
      name: CEP-NONPROD


And I still have the same error "Job manual_approval: Step reference task manual validation at version '0.198.0' which is not valid for the given job target"

Comment: @AlexPlanchon I think it just means this particular step can only be run on "server" pool that you define at task level, which trumps the pool you defined at job level.

Comment: You mean job level. You should define the pool at job level.