# ManualValidation under same job ADO

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

Could you please help me to understand and write manual validation step in same job using azure devops yaml pipeline

I have tried adding manual validation step under same job in -task and getting error

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean [Manual Validation task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/manual-validation-v0?view=azure-pipelines) in pipeline, then please note that this task is **only supported in YAML pipelines** and can **only be used in an agentless job** of a YAML pipeline.

We need to specify the `pool: server` for that task in an **agentless job**.

So, it's not supported if you want to add the [Manual Validation task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/manual-validation-v0?view=azure-pipelines) in an agent job with other agent steps/tasks(e.g PowerShell task or any other executable tasks). However, we can add Manual Validation task with other Agentless jobs supported tasks in the same job. See [Server jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#server-jobs) for details.

Official [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/manual-validation-v0?view=azure-pipelines#examples) for your reference:

```
jobs:
  - job: waitForValidation
    displayName: Wait for external validation
    pool: server
    timeoutInMinutes: 4320 # job times out in 3 days
    steps:
    - task: ManualValidation@0
      timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
      inputs:
        notifyUsers: |
          test@test.com
          example@example.com
        instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
        onTimeout: 'resume'
```

Comment: In my pipeline extends templates from central repository, hence bot using jobs. It all comes under one job and steps follwed by it. When i added under steps for manualvalidation task it is giving error “step reference task ‘ManualValidation’ at version ‘0.198.0’ which is not valid for the given job target.

Comment: @ChavaVenkat As mentioned in above answer, the manual validation task can only be used in an `agentless job` of a YAML pipeline. As we can see in the sample, we need to specify the `pool: server` for that task in an agentless job. Otherwise, you will receive the error. Reference another similar thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71593031/azure-pipeline-step-reference-task-manual-validation-at-version-0-198-which-is-n